# 'list' object is not callable for checking score accuracy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter, svm, confusion-matrix

I am creating a model using SVM. I wanted to save the classifier model and the parameters that was used into an excel and `.json` file, which will then be opened to see the best model out of all the `.json` files.

However, I got this error when I tried to run the second part of the code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9fd85866127d> in <module>
     88 for x in func:
     89     count=count+1
---> 90     train_val(x[0],x[1],x[2],count)
     91     end_time = time.time()

<ipython-input-4-9fd85866127d> in train_val(kernel, c, gamma, count)
     43             scoring.append(score(y_test, predictions))
     44         else:
---> 45             scoring.append(score(y_test, predictions,average='macro'))
     46 
     47     # saving kernel that is used to the list

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I didn't put anything that has the word `'list'` so it shouldn't have been overridden. What makes the score list uncallable? Thank you.

Comment: `callable` means function or function-like.  E.g. `foo()`.  You can't use a list that way.  Most likely your have created an list, when meant to create a function.  Make sure you understand why the syntax at that point is `function-like`, and two, make sure you understand the nature of that variable.

Comment: The content of `scores` has `list` type. not `function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create lists:

```
accuracy = []
precision = []
recall = []
f1 = []
...
```

and you define scores to hold these lists:

```
scores = [accuracy, precision, recall, f1]
```

Then you iterate over these lists:

```
for score in scores:
   ...
```

But inside that loop you use these lists as if they're functions:

```
score(y_test, predictions)
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you have created a list with same name as score and trying to use svm model on it is not possible so you need to change the name of the list variable so as to avoid the error in that case. Since list objects cannot be used as functions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).